# iOS - UserDefaults Source File Replacement

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I'm implementing backup functionalities in my app. Therefore I am backing up the UserDefaults source file where all UserDefaults are saved at the following path:

```
.../Library/Preferences/<Bundle Identifier>.plist
```

When the user restores a backup I'm replacing this file with the backup file.

**Problem:** The app continues to use the old UserDefaults. Only when I restart the app the changes apply. 
How can I tell Xcode to load the source file again?

Comment: Save your defaults to a plist file at the library preferences directory and manage it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not backup the plist file and you certainly should not attempt to replace the plist file. The fact that `[NS]UserDefaults` happens to use a specific plist file in your app's sandbox is an implementation detail you should not rely on. That could change in any future iOS update.

Use the API provided by `[NS]UserDefaults`.

When performing your backup, use `dictionaryRepresentation` to get a dictionary representing the contents. Then persist this dictionary any way you wish as part of your backup.

When performing a restore, load your persisted dictionary. Then use `resetStandardUserDefaults` to reset the user defaults and then iterate your retrieved dictionary storing each key/value pair into user defaults using the `set(_:forKey:)` method for each key/value pair.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I followed your steps exactly. But I still need to restart the app to make the changes apply. Any idea why? EDIT: I am storing data in the defaults

Comment: Without seeing relevant code and without specific details about what changes are requiring you to restart your app, it is impossible to provide any more details.

Comment: Found my mistake.. Thanks!